# Beaglebone u-boot: cross compiler failed to install

Tags: beagleboneblack, u-boot

I am following this [link](https://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black#BeagleBoneBlack-ARMCrossCompiler:GCC) to enable automatic boot from SD card.  After trying to install Linaro, I check for the GCC version:

```
${CC}gcc --version
```

It gives me this error:

```
bash: /home/debian/Desktop/gcc-linaro-6.4.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: No such file or directory
```

I search around, and this [link](https://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black#BeagleBoneBlack-ARMCrossCompiler:GCC) suggests using:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

That then gives me this error:

```
unable to locate package gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

This [link](https://bbs.nextthing.co/t/kernel-compile-help-stuck-at-unable-to-locate-package-gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf/11229) suggests using this instead:

```
 sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-none-eabi
```

I have not finished that process yet.  However, there are so many things I do not understand so far.  Beaglebone Black is a 32-bit system, why does the official u-boot guide point to a 64-bit version of Linaro?  The image I got is Debian Jessie 8.9 off the official site.  Is there a guide for u-boot at such starting point?  Thanks.

Comment: If you notice the link (https://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black#BeagleBoneBlack-ARMCrossCompiler:GCC) says, your host needs to be 64bit machine. I am guessing that your machine is 32-bit. Beagle bone black is 32-bit system, the link is pointing to 64-bit cross-compiler which will work on 64bit machine. The linaro toolchain is a cross compiler which will complie for apps/libs/kernel for your BBB (refer http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler for a bit more detail on cross compiler)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured this out.  The first part of the guide (before HDMI) is done on a computer with which you will flash your SD card.  After that, you boot into the BBB and do the rest.  This ambiguity kills me.